# The purpose of imposing some conditions on initial data

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems, sturm-liouville

I don't understand what is the purpose of imposing the condition $$\eqalign{
  & {A_0}^2 + {B_0}^2 \ne 0  \cr 
  & {A_1}^2 + {B_1}^2 \ne 0 \cr} $$Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 2):

If $A_0^2 + B_0^2 = 0$ we dont have have boundary condition. We cant solve the problem if we dont have boundary condition.

Comment: Thanks, I could'nt see that.